# Where should I put the composer.json file?

Tags: composer-php

I'm trying to use composer for a library, and in the docs they told me to put a line in my `composer.json` file (`require : xxxx`), but there is already a `composer.json` file present in the project.

I've tried to read the docs about composer, and they are saying to put the file inside the main folder. But there is already one `composer.json` file.

When I put in the `require` what I need (`setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "^2.0`), I get this error (I get the same error with the command `composer require setasign/fpdi-fpdf`) :

```
composer require setasign/fpdi-fpdf
Using version ^2.0 for setasign/fpdi-fpdf
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for setasign/fpdi No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by setasign/fpdi[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - setasign/fpdi-fpdf v2.0.0 requires setasign/fpdi ^2.0 -> satisfiable by setasign/fpdi[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[v2.0.0, No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[v2.0.1, No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[v2.0.2, No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Can only install one of: setasign/fpdi[v2.0.3, No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Installation request for setasign/fpdi-fpdf ^2.0 -> satisfiable by setasign/fpdi-fpdf[v2.0.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I'm not really familiar with composer, then I'm not able to know what to do with this error.

My `composer.json` file looks like this :

```
{
    "name": "setasign/fpdi",
    "homepage": "https://www.setasign.com/fpdi",
    "description": "FPDI is a collection of PHP classes facilitating developers to read pages from existing PDF documents and use them as templates in FPDF. Because it is also possible to use FPDI with TCPDF, there are no fixed dependencies defined. Please see suggestions for packages which evaluates the dependencies automatically.",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": [
        "pdf",
        "fpdi",
        "fpdf"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "setasign\\Fpdi\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "ext-zlib": "*"},
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jan Slabon",
            "email": "jan.slabon@setasign.com",
            "homepage": "https://www.setasign.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Maximilian Kresse",
            "email": "maximilian.kresse@setasign.com",
            "homepage": "https://www.setasign.com"
        }
    ],
    "suggest": {
        "setasign/fpdf": "FPDI will extend this class but as it is also possible to use \"tecnickcom/tcpdf\" as an alternative there's no fixed dependency configured.",
        "setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "Use this package to automatically evaluate dependencies to FPDF.",
        "setasign/fpdi-tcpdf": "Use this package to automatically evaluate dependencies to TCPDF."
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
        "setasign/fpdf": "~1.8",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "~6.2"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "setasign\\Fpdi\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

I've also asked for help in the library issues, and someone answered me :

> Why do you use the composer.json of FPDI?
>   For sure you need to create your own: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md !

That's why I don't really get it. (He didn't answered me afterwards, that's why I'm here).

Should I overwrite the existing `composer.json` file?
Or maybe I should put the file in another place?

Comment: How did you installed this package? You should not edit `composer.json` of dependency, you should have own `composer.json` in your project.

Comment: It was this ! I didn't know that I had to do my own composer.json file inside my project, thanks you very much !

Comment: If you have solved this problem, mark the answer that helped you as accepted or add your own answer describing how you solved the problem and accept it. Thanks to this, others will be able to easily see that your problem is solved. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't complicated at all, I just didn't know that I had to put the depedencies in my own `composer.json` file inside my project folder,  independently than the one in the library.

Thanks to Rob for his usefull help.

Answer (score 2):

You should have **one** `composer.json` file in your project and you should add new dependency into it. But not in random place, it should be inside of [`require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#the-require-key) section.

So if your old `composer.json` looks like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "some-old/dependency": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

After adding new dependency it should look like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "some-old/dependency": "1.0.*",
        "new/dependency": "^1.6"
    }
}
```

Where `^1.6` is a [constraint](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-version-constraints) for version of dependency you want to install.

---

If you don't know how to edit `composer.json`, you may use composer commands for this task:

```
composer require new/dependency
```

It will automatically add dependency to your `composer.json` and install it. It will also pick constraint for newest version of dependency, so this is probably the simplest way to do what you want.